# Display a message for each textbox - Validation - Jquery

Tags: jquery

Trying to display a message for each text box which the user didn't enter a value.

This is how HTML looks :

```
<tr>
<td class="TextBold">
<input name="ctl00$DefaultContent$ctl15" type="text" class="TextNormalJQH" style="width:36px;" /></td>
<td class="TextBold" align="left" valign="middle"></td>
</tr>
```

Jquery

```
 $(':text.TextNormalJQH').filter('[value=""]').closest('td').next().val() = "Answer is necessary";
```

The above statment throughs an error

Thanks in advance

BB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some work to do on your selectors.

```
$(':text[:empty]').parent('td').next('td').html("Answer is necessary");
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brentmn/xbEwG/